# python how to sort a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

i have to display a list shift wise like have to first show all day shift results then afternoon then night
but now it shows afternoon first then night then day
here is my code

views.py:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
    getall = self.request.GET.get("getall")

    if self.request.user:
        versions = LogVersion.objects.filter(
            form__airport__id=self.request.user.aerosimple_user.airport_id
        ).exclude(status=DRAFT)
        filters = self.request.GET.get("filters")
        tags = self.request.GET.get("tags")

        logs = Log.objects.none()
        result = Log.objects.none()

        for v in versions:
            if len(v.operation_logs.order_by('-id').all())>0:
                result = result | v.operation_logs.order_by('-id').all()
                result = result.exclude(shift_name = None).exclude(shift_name='')

    # if getall:
        if getall:
            return  Log.objects.filter(
            form__form__airport__id=self.request.user.aerosimple_user.airport.id)
        if filters is not None:
            filters = filters[:-2] if filters[-2:] == ',,' else filters
            filters_list = filters.split(',,')
            for filters in filters_list:
                log = result.filter(Q(type = filters) | Q(subtype = filters))
                if filters == 'Inspection Completed':
                    log = result.filter(Q(description = filters))
                elif log != []:
                    for r in result:
                        if r.tags is not None and filters in r.tags:
                            log  =result.filter(id=r.id)
                else:
                    log = result.filter(Q(type = filters) | Q(subtype = filters))
                logs = logs | log
            return logs.all()
        return result
```

how to sort it correctly

Comment: You can use the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)`(my_list, key=func)` method. You'll have to have some func that details how they should be sorted. Without seeing the list you want to sort, it's hard to know how to help

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
logs = sorted(logs, key=lambda x: dict(day=1, afternoon=2, night=3)[x.shift])
```